# using tf.keras.layers.Embedding for categorical variables in regression problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

Using the iris dataset as a hypothetical hello world example:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets

iris = datasets.load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(iris['data'], columns = iris['feature_names'])
df['iris_class'] = pd.Series(iris['target'], name = 'target_values')
df['iris_class_name'] = df['iris_class'].replace([0,1,2], ['iris-' + species for species in iris['target_names'].tolist()])
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace("[() ]", "")

print(df.head())
```

Let us say I want to use tf.keras.layers.Embedding instead of one-hot/dummy encoding as part of ANN for regression. e.g.:

**iris_class_name + sepalwidthcm + petallengthcm -> sepallengthcm**

where sepallengthcm is the dependent variable. I came across [this](https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/how-to-embed-categorical-features-which-are-strings-in-tensorflow/9381):

```
city_lookup = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(vocabulary = city_vocabulary, mask_token = None);
city_embedding= tf.keras.Sequential([
    city_lookup,
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(city_vocabulary) + 1, embedding_dimension)
  ], "city_embedding")
  
city = features["city"]
city_embedding_output = city_embedding(city)
```

but am not sure how to exactly use it in my use case. Any pointers very much welcome. Thanks!

Comment: All your variables, besides `iris_class_name`, are continuous, not categorical.

Comment: yes exactly ... it is an example with one cat. feature.

Comment: the answer in the link you shared adds `And you’ll typically tf.concat the output of that and other embeddings before invoking one or more dense layers.`, so your city_embedding_output will be concatenated with  sepalwidthcm + petallengthcm giving you a embedding_dimension+2 dimensional vector which you can use as input to your model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map `iris_class_name` to n-dimensional vector representations and then concatenate with the other continuous features:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

iris = datasets.load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(iris['data'], columns = iris['feature_names'])
df['iris_class'] = pd.Series(iris['target'], name = 'target_values')
df['iris_class_name'] = df['iris_class'].replace([0,1,2], ['iris-' + species for species in iris['target_names'].tolist()])
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace("[() ]", "")

vocab = df['iris_class_name'].unique()
embedding_dimension = 10
lookup = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(vocabulary = vocab, mask_token = None)
embedding= tf.keras.Sequential([
    lookup,
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(vocab) + 1, embedding_dimension)
  ])
  
names = df['iris_class_name'].to_numpy()
embedding_output = embedding(names)

features = np.concatenate((embedding_output, df[['sepalwidthcm', 'petallengthcm']].to_numpy()), axis=-1)

print(features.shape)
```

```
(150, 12)
```

Since you have 3 unique iris class names, you could also simply create an integer-to-vector dictionary manually, but it is up to you.

Comment: thanks - the iris was just chosen as an example.